# How to create a class A same another class B, make typescript not throw type error, class B contain member visibility property

Tags: typescript, class, extends

My use case like this, in libray I export a class A.
simplify library code like this

**library.ts**

```js
class Base {
  public foo!: number;
  private bar!: string;
  constructor(conf: {
    [index:string]: any
  }) {
    this.foo = conf.foo
    this.bar = conf.bar
  }
  private m1() {
    console.log(this.foo)
  }
  public m2() {
    this.m1()
    console.log(this.bar)
  }
}
interface AParentConf {
  a: number
  b: number
  c: string
  foo?: number
  bar?: string
  [index:string]: any
}
class AParent extends Base {
  public a!:number
  protected b!:number
  private c!:string;
  constructor(conf: AParentConf) {
    super(conf)
    this.a = conf.a
    this.b = conf.b
    this.c = conf.c
  }
  private m3() {
    console.log(this.c)
  }
  public m4() {
    this.m3()
    console.log(this.b)
  }
}
export interface AConfig extends AParentConf {
  d: number
  e: number
}

export default class A extends AParent {
  public d!: number
  private e!: number

  constructor(conf: AConfig) {
    super(conf)
    this.d = conf.d
    this.e = conf.e
  }
  
  protected m5() {
    console.log(this.e)
  }

  public m6() {
    this.m5()
    console.log(this.d)
  }
}
```

In bussiness code we use libray like this

**business.ts**

```js
import A from 'library'

let a: A = new A({
  d: 1,
  e: 1,
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 'a'
});
```

but now library architecture and data structure totally  change ,we hope the business layer code may cost less to change, so we design a new architecture like this

**new-library.ts**

```
import A, { AConfig } from './library.ts'

interface ExtendsAConfig extends AConfig {
  extraConfig?: {
    [index: string]: any
  }
}

class AdapterA extends A {
  public override  d!: number
  public override  m6() {
    console.log(this.d)
  }
  // override all A public method
  constructor(conf: ExtendsAConfig) {
    super(conf)
    this.d = conf?.extraConfig?.d
  }
}


export default class MixinA extends AdapterA {
  // mixinA will override all adapterA method
  public override  d!: number
  public override  m6() {
  }
  // override all AdapterA public method
  constructor(conf: ExtendsAConfig) {
    super(conf)
    const model = conf?.extraConfig?.model ?? 'A'
    if(model === 'mixinA') {
      return this
    } else if(model === 'adapter') {
      return new AdapterA(conf)
    } else {
      return new A(conf)
    }
  }
}
```

now in business code if we want't use new feature we just add new config, like this

**business.ts**

```js
import A from 'library'

let a: A = new A({
  d: 1,
  e: 1,
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 'a',
  extraConfig: {
    // some new config
  }
});
```

but in this way ,because MixinA extends AdapterA and AdpaterA extends A, so AdapterA will call A constructor function and ..., but we don't want this happen so we change new-library like this

```js
import type TypeA  from './A'
import { AConfig } from './A'
import A from './A'

interface ExtendsAConfig extends AConfig {
  extraConfig?: {
    [index: string]: any
  }
}

// simulate all A public feature  ts will throw error
// simulate private or protected method ts2720 error
class AdapterA implements TypeA {
  public foo!: number;
  private bar!: string;
  public a!: number;
  protected b!:number
  private c!:string;
  private e!:number;
  public d!: number
  private m1() {
  }
  public m2() {

  }
  private m3() {
  }
  public m4() {
  }
  protected m5() {}
  public m6() {
  }
  constructor(conf: ExtendsAConfig) {
    // do some new logic
  }
}


export default class MixinA extends AdapterA {
  // mixinA will override all adapterA method
  public override  d!: number
  public override  m6() {
  }

  constructor(conf: ExtendsAConfig) {
    super(conf)
    const model = conf?.extraConfig?.model ?? 'A'
    if(model === 'mixinA') {
      return this
    } else if(model === 'adapter') {
      return new AdapterA(conf)
    } else {
      // throw error MixinA not like A type
      return new A(conf)
    }
  }
}
```

but in typescript protected,... can't extend this make MixinA not same export A.

so there is a way we can export this MixinA like A type.and make business code less change and no type error.

mixinA not just a class factory, is feature like class A, but in library internal, depend on business code  config to change mixin how to work.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the code so it's a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs and get to work on it?  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to make of your commented out fields and neither is my IDE.  Same with the comments that describe code.  Ideally you'd provide something where, when we paste it into our own IDEs, your problem (and only your problem) jumps out at us.

Comment: Your mixin is not really a mixin. It's a factory function. Model it as one, without `class`.